# How to use python script to download JSON from the net using API

Tags: python, json, mako

I am new with the python.
Can anyone tell me how to download JSON file from given API in python and then save as HTML using mako or jinja?

1. Use python script to download JSON from the net using the API.

   - API to use http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Answer (score 1):

You use requests module to get the json by following code

```
import requests
url = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22"
res = requests.get(url)
if res.ok:
    res.json()
```

For additional resource you can follow this [link](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
requests.get(URL).json()
```